# React router using formate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using the react-router for the below code, but i am not sure that is correct or not for the format, I can run it without error. Please advice me if anything wrong with it.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <hr />
        <Link to="/Brand">Brand</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <Link to="/home">Home</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <Link to="/Users">Users</Link> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <Link to="/Create">Create</Link>
        <hr />
        <Route path="/Users">
          <Users
            users={this.state.users}
            handleUserOpen={this.handleUserOpen}
            handleDeleteUsers={this.handleDeleteUsers}
            handleDeleteUser={this.handleDeleteUser}
          />
          <UserModal
            selectedUser={this.state.selectedUser}
            viewUser={this.state.viewUser}
            handleClearSelectedUser={this.handleClearSelectedUser}
          />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/Create">
          <AddUser
            handleAddUser={this.handleAddUser}
            users={this.state.users}
          />
        </Route>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What format it is?

Comment: just wondering is it ok to write above code as normally people will do <Route path="/xxxxx" component={xxxx}>

Comment: "Normally" people do like this also `<Route path="/x"><YourComp /></Route>`

Comment: btw, Why don't you add `exact` on `<Route />`?

Comment: exact on <Route />?  what is it for?

Comment: `<Route exact path="/example" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use in itself doesn't look wrong to me. However, the way I usually deal with this is by declaring the routes in a separate file in src.

Here's what it'd look like:

## src/Routes.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './pages/Home';
import Brand from './pages/Brand';
import Users from './pages/Users';
import Create from './pages/Create';

export default function Routes() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component ={ Home } />
                <Route path="/brand" component={ Brand } />
                <Route path="/users" component={ Users } />
                <Route path="/create" component={ Create } />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

The keyword "exact" in the route means it'll be the home route. You'll usually assign it to the "/" route, like on the example above.

## src/App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './global.css'
import Routes from './routes';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes />
  );
}

export default App;
```

The components would look pretty much like you showed. The Link should work without issues if you declared all of them in Routes.js.

Comment: I also would add a `Route` without `path` with a `Redirect` component `to='/404'` to handle not found pages. :-)

Comment: thanks for helping me, i got one question, they are using the same state as users in the Users and AddUser component and they are on two different pages, how could they use the same state in two-component?since my teacher tell me i can not use <Route path="/x"><YourComp /></Route> and the correct way is <Route path="/xxxxx" component={xxxx}>, it could not pass any state to other component if i use< Route path="/xxxxx" component={xxxx}>so i was confused and i was thinking my code is wrong, but it still works without issue.

Comment: We're using the React Router to help the users navigate through multiple pages. The only way I dealt with this in the past is by using a Node.js API in the back to return any data necessary to the page from a database. If you're trying to send props through, I would recommend that you use them as children to the Home component and manage their visibilities. Thus, you can send Home (parent) state as props to children, as well as a setState function for the children to callback and alter the state for the parent component.

Comment: thanks for your expatiation<Route path="/Create">
          <AddUser
            handleAddUser={this.handleAddUser}
            users={this.state.users}
          /> if i use above code, is it correct? 
As you mentioned before, Does the Home page shows all components if i need to send props?

Comment: It becomes a matter of managing visibility. You could use the state to do so. homeVisible: true, addUserVisible: false. You put a handler on click of a button, for example, where going to Add User sets state true for it and false for home. In the Add User component, for the container div, use the property style to show it or not. const style = { props.addUserVisible ? 'block' : none } // <div className="add-user-container" style={style}.